# Wordpress/WooCommerce cron troubles

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cron

I am trying to create a cron job that turns WooCommerce products from publish to draft, and to draft from publish depending on stock and the low stock amount field. At first i get it to run, i had to tweak it a bit and now nothing happens. I adjusted some code i found here: [How to auto draft WooCommerce product on specific date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71170261/how-to-auto-draft-woocommerce-product-on-specific-date)

Here is the code i have been using:

```
// Schedule an action if it's not already scheduled
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'check_daily_for_change_product_status' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'check_daily_for_change_product_status' );
}

// Hook into that action that'll fire every three minutes
add_action( 'check_daily_for_change_product_status', 'check_daily_for_change_product_status_func' );
function check_daily_for_change_product_status_func() {
    
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => array("publish", "draft")
    );

    $get_products = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $get_products->have_posts() ){ while ( $get_products->have_posts() ) { $get_products->the_post();

        $produkt_kat =  get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
        foreach ($produkt_kat as $kat_id)   
        {   
            $lagerstyring = false;
            $slaa_til = get_field( "lavt_lager", $kat_id );
            if ($slaa_til != false)
            {
                $lagerstyring = true;
                $to = get_field("deaktiverings_emails", $kat_id);
                break;
            }
                
        }
                                                                              
            $product_id = get_the_ID();
            $admin_lager = $product_id->get_manage_stock();
            $low_stock_amount = $product_id->get_low_stock_amount();
            $lager = $product_id->get_stock_quantity();
            $produktnavn = $product_id->get_name();
            $produkturl = get_permalink($product_id);
            $tidspunkt = current_time();
            
            if ($admin_lager == true && $lagerstyring == true)
            {
                if ($low_stock_amount >= $lager)
                    {
                    $my_post = array(
                    'ID'           => get_the_ID(),
                    'post_status'  => 'draft',
                    );
                    wp_update_post( $my_post );
                    wp_mail( $to, "Vare slået fra", "Denne vare er blevet automatisk slået fra da den har en lav lagerbeholdning: <br /><b>" . $produktnavn . "</b><br />" . $produkturl . "<br />" . $tidspunkt, 'Content-type: text/html', ); 
                    }
                
                if ($lager > $low_stock_amount && $low_stock_amount != null)
                    {
                    $my_post = array(
                    'ID'           => get_the_ID(),
                    'post_status'  => 'publish',
                    );
                    wp_update_post( $my_post );
                    wp_mail( $to, "Vare slået til", "Denne vare er blevet automatisk udgivet, da dens lagerbeholdning er øget: <br /><b>" . $produktnavn . "</b><br />" . $produkturl . "<br />" . $tidspunkt , 'Content-type: text/html', );   
                    }
                
                    
        }
                                                                                
    } wp_reset_postdata(); }

}
```

Comment: First use WP Crontrol to see and test is your cron running properly. Also this is realy heavy task if you have alot of products. This impacts your SEO too. But if you realy must do it i would recommend instead of looping all products every day to check when someone place an order. This way you will compare less products if a product have to be drafted or not. If order status changes and products are restocked again check only few products. When u update product you can run check again. To me this is the more optimal solution.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The problem is its getting stock changes from a physical shop. This updates stock, but we dont receive mails about low stock and sometimes there will be a product online with 2 remaining, but in reality we have sold 98/100 and the last 2 has been broken/stolen/gone bad, so we no longer have the product. With this i can turn it off online when there's only a few products are remaining. Perhaps i should look into splitting it into smaller bits to use minimal resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who might need this code, I figured it out and it works now.

```
// Schedule an action if it's not already scheduled
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'check_daily_for_change_product_status' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'check_daily_for_change_product_status' );
}

// Hook into that action that'll fire every three minutes
add_action( 'check_daily_for_change_product_status', 'check_daily_for_change_product_status_func' );
function check_daily_for_change_product_status_func() {
    
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => "product",
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => array("publish", "draft")
    );

    $get_products = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $get_products->have_posts() ){ while ( $get_products->have_posts() ) { $get_products->the_post();

        $produkt_kat =  get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
        foreach ($produkt_kat as $kat_id)   
        {   
            $lagerstyring = false;
            $slaa_til = get_field( "lavt_lager", $kat_id );
            if ($slaa_til != false)
            {
                $lagerstyring = true;
                $to = get_field("deaktiverings_emails", $kat_id);
                break;
            }
                
        }
                                                                              
            global $product;                                                      
            $product_id = get_the_ID();
            $admin_lager = $product->get_manage_stock();
            $low_stock_amount = $product->get_low_stock_amount();
            $lager = $product->get_stock_quantity();
            $produktnavn = $product->get_name();
            $produkturl = $product->get_permalink();
            $tidspunkt = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', current_time('timestamp'));
            
            if ($admin_lager == true && $lagerstyring == true)
            {
                if ($low_stock_amount >= $lager)
                    {
                    $my_post = array(
                    'ID'           => get_the_ID(),
                    'post_status'  => 'draft',
                    );
                    wp_update_post( $my_post );
                    wp_mail( $to, "Vare slået fra", "Denne vare er blevet automatisk slået fra da den har en lav lagerbeholdning: <br /><b>" . $produktnavn . "</b><br />" . $produkturl . "<br />" . $tidspunkt, 'Content-type: text/html', ); 
                    }
                
                if ($lager > $low_stock_amount && $low_stock_amount != null)
                    {
                    $my_post = array(
                    'ID'           => get_the_ID(),
                    'post_status'  => 'publish',
                    );
                    wp_update_post( $my_post );
                    wp_mail( $to, "Vare slået til", "Denne vare er blevet automatisk udgivet, da dens lagerbeholdning er øget: <br /><b>" . $produktnavn . "</b><br />" . $produkturl . "<br />" . $tidspunkt , 'Content-type: text/html', );   
                    }
                
                    
        }
                                                                                
    } 
                                      wp_reset_postdata(); }

}
```